# UINavigationController's Toolbar should appear above content

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I'm facing the problem that I want to have the toolbar of UINavigationController to appear over the content.

Right now, subviews inside the navigation controller are resized to fit: `V:|[myview][toolbar]|`

However, I'd appreciate having the following: `V:|[myview]|`, where the toolbar is still at the bottom of course.

Since I'm using the navigationController's toolbar, I have no influence on the constraints.

Does anyone have suggestions how to get the effect I'm looking for?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I have to use `bottomLayoutGuide` instead of `|` for the constraint.

So, the format string should look like `V:[topLayoutGuide][myView][bottomLayoutGuide]`, where `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` are the same called properties on `UIViewController'.